# The unanswered question: Where do electrons get their ever-lasting circulating energy?

Tags: electrons, energy-conservation, atomic-physics, orbitals

This question has been asked by many others like me, and in so many forums as well as here, and answered by many as well, and I still do not find the answer. The question is "Where do electrons get their ever-lasting circulating energy?". All answers somehow start explaining about the descreet energy levels of the electrons (BUT not how these emerged at the first place), the theories about why electrons do not crash into the nucleus, and the uncertainty principle etc. But no one so far really answers the main question - where the electrons get their initial energy from, the energy they need to start operating at all? Is it the energy they got at the beginning, by the proposed Big Bang of the Universe, or how? Is this a question that is still unanswered by science?

Comment: What ever-lasting circulating energy? This question is very confused about physics.

Comment: Perhaps the root of this question is the origin of zero-point energy.

Comment: Seems to me that - yes - zero-point energy has a lot to do with my question and I will educate myself about it.

Comment: this answer of mine is relevant, as far as our present models go https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/107717/if-energy-can-neither-be-created-nor-be-destroyed-what-is-the-ultimate-source-of/226812#226812

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, we don't know how the universe got started, so a valid answer would just be that there's some amount of energy available and distributed throughout all physical systems, and we can't say where it came from.

(If we take into account the expansion of the universe then the total energy isn't constant, but it changes in a predictable way.)

However, for the specific case of an atom I can be a bit more useful: an electron in an atom has *less* energy than an electron by itself. This makes sense: things generally tend towards a state of lower energy, so if an atom had positive energy (instead of negative) it would break apart. If you start with a proton and an electron separated from each other, they will attract thanks to the electromagnetic force, and end up together in a state of lower energy. The difference will be radiated away as electromagnetic waves, and will disperse through the universe.

Comment: Thank you so much! You completely answer my question! There are so few people that are ready to admit that the answer is not yet found, and yet this is the satisfactory answer  I was looking for - so I do not need to spend any more hours looking for an unexisting answer. Thank you so much! (And for the additional info, too)

Comment: Javier, you say "the difference will be radiated away as electromagnetic waves..."   Is this the source of the electromagnetic field that surrounds a bar magnet?

Comment: @foolishmuse No. The field surrounding a magnet is static. This is a dynamic process, which emits waves - it's a different kind of field.

Comment: Javier, another question for you... "If you start with a proton and an electron separated from each other, they will attract thanks to the electromagnetic force, and end up together in a state of lower energy. " Can you explain why the two particles, being in a way "the perfect match" for one another, still would not end up with zero energy instead? I do not mean here an electron crashing into the proton and aborting the entire atomic structure, but rather a "perfectly balanced", and further nonreactive - atom of matter?

Comment: They do end up perfectly balanced and nonreactive - it's just that this doesn't imply zero energy. The total energy of the atom is *less* than that of the separated proton and electron; that's what being stable means.